# jQuery Autocomplete plugin not working with jQuery 1.4.1

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I've been using the JQuery Autocomplete plugin with JQuery version 1.3.2, and it has been working great.  I recently updated JQuery in my project to version 1.4.2, and the Autocomplete plugin is now broken.  The JQuery code to add items to a textbox on my web page doesn't seem to be getting called at all.  Does anyone know if the JQuery Autocomplete plugin is incompatible with JQuery version 1.4.2, and if there is a fix for this problem?  Here is some sample code I've built in an ASP.Net web site (which works fine if I change the JQuery file to jquery-1.3.2.js, but nothing happens using jquery-1.4.2.js):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"    Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events    Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
        $(':input:text:id$=sapleUser').autocomplete(data);
    }); 
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    API Reference: <input id="sapleUser" autocomplete="off" type="text" runat="server" /> (try "C" or "E")  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As there are many autocomplete plugins I would recommend looking to see if the one you are using has an update to support 1.4.1

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using (there are a few)?  Also are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm using the 1.1 version of the Jorn Zaefferer Autocomplete plugin, just checked his website (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), and 1.1 is the latest version.  I'm not getting any errors, the autocomplete jquery just doesn't seem to get run at all.

Comment: @Russ - Can you post the code you're using to run it?  Also keep in mind jQuery 1.4 requires valid JSON (1.3 was more forgiving) coming back, if you're using JSON look at the console, make sure it's valid: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you'd upgrade to 1.4.1 instead of 1.4.2?

Comment: I have added sample code, and updated to JQuery 1.4.2. - I had originally made this update when JQuery 1.4.1 was current, and only realized I had this problem yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Autocomplete plugin is compatible with JQuery ver 1.4.1 and 1.4.2.  The problem was caused by my JQuery selector: $(':input:text:id$=sapleUser'), which appears not to be compatible with the 1.4.x versions of JQuery.  I modified the selector to:  $('input[id$=sapleUser]'), and it is now working again.